# GIT SKIP EMPTY DIRECTORIES

Tags: linux, git, ssh, vps

Well I just noticed something very peculiar about ig, I don't know if it already existed or not, well I have this directory

```
directorio
|-- .Module
|   |-- Resources
|       |-- css
|       |-- js
|       |-- images
|   |-- Views
|   |-- Controllers
|   |-- .conf.conf
```

It is a .Modulo directory (hidden) that has that structure everything is perfect, I use it as a template it is already registered in a commit so to be able to use it I use `cp -r .Module NewModule`
and everything was perfect until then, and I created a new commit for that duplicate directory, the problem is when I want to go back to the first commit where I did not have a duplicate of the template since the duplicate is there and does not disappear temporarily, and the only thing I could do is that in empty directories create some files, is this normal for git?

Using empty directory in git

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+empty+directory , https://archive.kernel.org/oldwiki/git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq.html#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F